# jQuery mCustomScrollbar function after scrollTop

Tags: jquery, scrollto, mcustomscrollbar

I'm using jQuery `mCustomScrollbar` on my website.

I'm using 2 functions, using the same `onClick` action:

```
$('body').on('click', '.infos_open', function () {
```

First I want my custom content to scroll back:

```
$(".mCustomScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",0);
```

And once it's done, another function (as an example):

```
$('.infos_fixed').removeClass('fixed');
```

But I can't figure out how to use a callback to do this.

here is what I've tried:

```
$('body').on('click', '.infos_open', function () {

     $(".mCustomScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",0, function(){ 

          $('.infos_fixed').removeClass('fixed');

     });
});
```

And here is another solution I tried, which is not working:

```
$('body').on('click', '.infos_open', function () {

    $(".mCustomScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",0, {
        scrollInertia: 3000,
        callbacks: {
            onScroll: function(){

                $('.infos_fixed').removeClass('fixed');

            }
        }
    });

});
```

Can't find more information about this, I need to keep the exact syntax `"$('body').on('click', '.infos_open', function () {"`

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Have you looked at http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#callbacks-section

Comment: @artm, yes I had a look, please take a look at my edited question, the second option... which is not working